# Linking with external library using absolute position in QMake

Tags: qmake

I want to link to an external library like this:

```
win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$(LOCALAPPDATA)/External_program/lib/external_lib.dll.a
```

When I deploy the executable it won't work unless it's in the same directory as the `.dll`, even if it is where it's expected to be.

How do I fix this to allow the `.exe` to find the library without having to copy the dll to the directory itself?

Comment: That has nothing to do with qmake. DLL dependencies (except LoadLibrary() stuff) are resolved by OS while loading the program. Therefore, all DLLs must be either in the current directory or on the PATH.

Comment: Thanks! could you add that as an answe so that I could pick yours!